# Custom Admin Theme not loading

Tags: orchardcms

I created a new Admin theme based on *TheAdmin* in a separate csproj. I've implemented the `IThemeSelector` to override the default admin theme. Unfortunately, no styles are loaded from the theme, as if not theme was selected, instead the default theme is loaded.
When I move the styles, scripts and views back into the Themes module/project, all works well.

One more thing worth mentioning

```cs
namespace MyAdminTheme
{
  public class ThemeSelector : IThemeSelector
  {
    public ThemeSelectorResult GetTheme(RequestContext context) 
    {
        if (AdminFilter.IsApplied(context))
        {
            return new ThemeSelectorResult { 
                Priority = 110, 
                ThemeName = "My Admin Theme" 
            };
        }

        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

When I provide an invalid `ThemeName`, **no styles** are loaded. If I provide a correct theme name, then the default *TheAdmin* theme gets selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this was confusing: [Custom Admin Theme - disccusion](https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/258854)

Anyhow, to make this work I had to enable the theme from the orchard command line

```
c:\MyOrchard\Orchard.Web> .\bin\Orchard.exe

orchard> feature enable MyAdmin
```

All works fine now.